# MATLAB function graphallshortestpaths not returning symmetric matrix

Tags: matlab, shortest-path, adjacency-matrix

I am using the MATLAB function graphallshortestpaths to compute shortest paths between vertices of an undirected network. The undirected network is given as a weighted edge list file, which you can find [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/n-otter/PH-roadmap/master/data_sets/genome_edge_list).

This is the MATLAB code that I use to compute the shortest paths:

```
A=load('genome_edge_list');

%Extract the edges
E=[A(:,1);A(:,2)]; 

%Extract the vertices
V=unique(E); 

%N is the number of vertices
N=length(V); 

%Take the inverse of the weights
A(:,3)=1./A(:,3);

%Create a sparse weighted adjacency matrix
B=sparse(A(:,1),A(:,2),A(:,3),N,N);

%Make B symmetric
B=sparse(full(B)+full(B)');

%Compute shortest paths
D=graphallshortestpaths(B,'directed',false);
```

Now, the matrix D that MATLAB gives as output is not symmetric. However, since the input to graphallshortestpaths is a symmetric matrix in sparse format, the output ought to be a symmetric matrix. So what am I doing wrong?

The only related question that I could find on mathworks is [this](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/248201-why-the-command-of-finding-the-all-short-paths-for-graph-graphallshortestpaths-give-me-wrong-num) question, however in that question the OP clearly is not giving a symmetric matrix as input, which explains why the matrix returned by MATLAB is not symmetric.

**EDIT:**

To see how far off D and D' are, I computed the following:

```
E=D';
C=D==E;
find(C==0)
```

this returns the following linear indices:

```
 33133
 543038
 1363077
 1398421
 1398786
 1399373
```

but the values of D and E at those indices are the same, e.g. D(33133)= 0.1024=E(33133). Now, if I take the difference of the two matrices, then I find that the difference at those indices is -1.0000e-05. It therefore seems to be a rounding error, as @beaker points out. However, as I write in my comment below, I don't understand how this can occur, as graphsallshortestpaths computes the distance between node i and j only once, so the values of D(i,j) and D(i,j) should be the result of the same computation.

Comment: How far are the values off by? The only thing I can think of is floating point precision. Also, I think the third line should be `V=unique(E);` since `H` is undefined, but I can't see how that could cause the problem even if `H` was already defined elsewhere.

Comment: @beaker thanks, that was a typo. I checked how far the values are off with `C=D==D.'` and `find(C==0)` gives me a list of six indices for which D and D.' should be different. However, the values for those indices are the same, so I am baffled as to why `issymmetric(D)` returns 0.

Comment: A small example would help.

Comment: @beaker, I checked again by computing the difference of the two matrices, and at those six indices they have a difference of -1.0000e-05. So this seems to be a rounding problem. However, I can't see where it occurs, as the distance between node i and node j should be computed only once by graphsallshortestpaths, so the value at D(j,i) should be the same as the value at D(i,j).

Comment: @beaker I'll add an example to the question.

Comment: `D(i,j)` is not necessarily going to be the same as `D(j,i)` as they are calculated independently.

Comment: @beaker but since this is an undirected graph, shouldn't the distance be computed only once?

Comment: The documentation doesn't specifically say what algorithm they're using, but something like Floyd-Warshall is not specific to undirected graphs, so it calculates both paths.

Comment: @beaker Right, but in the documentation there is written `%GRAPHALLSHORTESTPATHS(...,'DIRECTED',false) indicates that the graph G is
% undirected, the upper triangle of the G is ignored. Default is true.` Therefore the distance should be computed only once. Am I missing something?

Comment: Not necessarily. That could simply mean that when finding an edge weight in `G`, if `i > j`, it looks up `G(j, i)` instead of `G(i, j)`.

Comment: @beaker Okay, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Couple or remarks:

- As @beaker mentioned in the comment, it could well be a numerical issue. I would be particularly weary of the line where you take the inverse and do `A(:,3)=1./A(:,3);`. Try to output some debug values and see if this inverse does what you intended.
- On the line where you make `B` symmetric: are you sure you want to do `full(b)'` and not `full(b).'`? The first one takes the hermitian, the second the transpose!
- Also on the same line where you make `B` symmetric: perhaps you are missing a `0.5` factor in there? So instead of `B=sparse(full(B)+full(B)');` something like `B=sparse((full(B)+full(B).').*0.5);` (see [this answer](https://ch.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/309569-make-an-existing-matrix-symmetric)).

I also think you unintentionally wrote `H` instead of `E` on the second line, right?

Comment: Thanks for the remarks. Even if I don't take the inverse of the weights `issymmetric(D)` still returns 0, and the line `A(:,3)=1./A(:,3)` actually does what I want it to do. As for your second remark, since I am dealing with real numbers it doesn't make a difference whether I am taking the hermitian or the transpose.

Comment: Finally, as I have a list of weighted edges of an undirected graph, with no repetitions of edges in the list, adding the transpose of the matrix to itself is the right way to get a weighted symmetric adjacency matrix, as I won't be duplicating any values, while with `(full(B)+full(B).')*05` I would divide all the weights in half, which is not what I want to do.